# order routing for a fill

Tags: futures, algorithmic-trading, algorithm, order

Lets assume a FIFO rules in futures, I buy a contract and id like to sell it. Should I estimate the possibilite of orders on opposite side would be filled first? If I watch new orders incoming at new discovery price in the session could I be sure that the market will have to go now in my direction?

Tx